# About Numpy shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shapes

I'm new to numpy & have a question about it :

according to docs.scipy.org, the "shape" method is "the dimensions of the array. For a matrix with n rows and m columns, shape will be (n,m)"

Suppose I am to create a simple array as below:

```
np.array([[0,2,4],[1,3,5]])
```

Using the "shape" method, it returns (2,3) (i.e. the array has 2 rows & 3 columns)

However, for an array ([0,2,4]), the shape method would return (3,) (which means it has 3 rows according to the definition above)

I'm confused : the array ([0,2,4]) should have 3 columns not 3 rows so I expect it to return (,3) instead.

Can anyone help to clarify ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't focus on the labels, `rows` and `columns`.  Just count the number of dimensions - 1,2, 3 etc.  Rows and columns make most sense when talking about a 2d array.  With a 1d array, it makes more sense to talk of elements.  But that's just convention.

Comment: Oh great Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

This is just notation - in Python, tuples are distinguished from expression grouping (or order of operations stuff) by the use of commas - that is, `(1,2,3)` is a tuple and `(2x + 4) ** 5` contains an expression `2x + 4`. In order to keep single-element tuples distinct from single-element expressions, which would otherwise be ambiguous (`(1)` vs `(1)` - which is the single-element tuple and which a simple expression that evaluates to `1`?), we use a trailing comma to denote tuple-ness.

What you're getting is a single dimension response, since there's only one dimension to measure, packed into a `tuple` type.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy supports not only 2-dimensional arrays, but multi-dimensional arrays, and by multi-dimension I mean 1-D, 2-D, 3-D .... n-D, And there is a format for representing respective dimension array. The `len` of `array.shape` would get you the number of dimensions of that array. If the array is 1-D, the there is no need to represent as `(m, n)` or if the array is 3-D then it `(m, n)` would not be sufficient to represent its dimensions.

So the output of `array.shape` would not always be in `(m, n)` format, it would depend upon the array itself and you will get different outputs for different dimensions.